# Python f2py reload changed module

Tags: python-3.x, f2py

I am new to programming and `python`. I have managed to use `f2py` to import a fortran module to `python`. However there is a small problem i can not figure out. When I change the fortran code and use again `f2py` to refresh the module, the compiler still recognizes the first version of the module. How can I force it to refresh the module? I have read about the `importlib.reload`, but it does not change anything for me. I am refering to `python3.7`.

The fortran code two.f90 is:

```
module two
 implicit none

 contains

 subroutine twofunc(x,y)
     real,intent(in) :: x
     real,intent(out) :: y
     y = x*x
 end subroutine twofunc

end module
```

Then i change it to :

```
module two
implicit none

contains

subroutine twofunc(x,y)
    real,intent(in) :: x
    real,intent(out) :: y
    y = x*x*x
  end subroutine twofunc

end module.
```

It is just a test code.
Then, I ran f2py. Then in Spyder:

```
import importlib
import two 
importlib.reload(one10)
y=two.two.twofunc(4)
print(y)
```

Despite changing the code from x^2 to x^3 it still gives me 16 as a result.

Comment: Please add minimal reproducable example.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Put more details of the issue that you are facing. Include the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `reload` command does not work for all cases. f2py modules, probably because they contain compiled code, cannot be reloaded in general.

You need to restart the kernel to iterate with extension module development (menu "consoles" -> restart kernel or right-clic on the console tab -> restart kernel).